# How to properly throw an error in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building an SVG component that takes a filename without extension. I want to force this and throw an error if the extension is used though.

Since I have a ES6 compiler I am simply using this:

```
if (this.name.includes('.svg')) {
    throw 'Do not use the svg extension';
}
```

Is this a proper way to throw an error in Vue.js or is there a better way? Currently I am getting 2 warnings when I implement this and test it out.

I am getting a [Vue warn] with stacktrace and my own error. Preferably I would just like to throw a simply error message in the console to signify what a user did wrong.

Any thoughts on this approach or tips to handle this better in Vue.js or javscript in general?

Comment: That is a correct approach I think, the [vue warn] you are getting is just more specific about the error you throw mentioning when the error originated including your component name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the standard TypeError:

> Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when a variable or parameter is not of a valid type.

```
throw new TypeError("Do not use the svg extension", filename)
```

[TypeError-MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError)

Comment: He is not asking how to throw an errow. You just gave the documentation link for typerror. He knows how to throw an error and he is doing that, he is asking why he is getting vue warn

Comment: @user7814783 I think he is also asking the better way to throw this kind of error.

Comment: A bit of both yes I just want confirmation and a possible solution or answer to why the second error also shows. I guess I will update to TypeError and leave the double error messages `as is` for now.

Answer (score 2):

> When Error is used like a function -- without new, it will return an Error object. Therefore, a mere call to Error will produce the same output that constructing an Error object via the new keyword would.

```
throw new Error('Error text.');
```

> *Besides the generic Error constructor, there are seven other core error constructors in JavaScript. For client-side exceptions, see Exception handling statements.*
>
> **EvalError**
>   Creates an instance representing an error that occurs regarding the global function eval().
>
> **InternalError**
>   Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when an internal error in the JavaScript engine is thrown. E.g. "too much recursion".
>
> **RangeError**
>   Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when a numeric variable or parameter is outside of its valid range.
>   ReferenceError
>   Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when de-referencing an invalid reference.
>
> **SyntaxError**
>   Creates an instance representing a syntax error that occurs while parsing code in eval().
>
> **TypeError**
>   Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when a variable or parameter is not of a valid type.
>
> **URIError**
>   Creates an instance representing an error that occurs when encodeURI() or decodeURI() are passed invalid parameters.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.